# Restricting the right scroll for scroll view at some conditions

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I was working with scroll view with ten pages, user can scroll in both directions with gesture and button actions. But there are some situations in which a toggle button in view is on we need to stop right side scrolling up to user fills the data once he fills the data scrollview need to start scrolling again. one more situation is when toggle is on user need to skip all views and directly scroll to last view. I need to maintain page count on screen too.